# assertEqual getting failed while values are same

Tags: python, django, testing

I have below test case assert code

```
self.assertEqual(
            response.data['results'],
            [
                ('id', self.bookmark.id),
                ('title', self.bookmark.title),
                ('color', self.bookmark.color),
                ('user', self.bookmark.user.id),
                ('project', self.bookmark.project.id),
            ]
        )
```

response.data['result'] is :

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 7), ('title', 'bookmark'), ('color', 'yellow'), ('user', 2), ('project', 1)])]
```

compare list value is :

```
[('id', 7), ('title', 'bookmark'), ('color', 'yellow'), ('user', 2), ('project', 1)]
```

failure msg :

```
AssertionError: [OrderedDict([('id', 7), ('title', 'bookma[52 chars]1)])] != [('id', 7), ('title', 'bookmark'), ('color[37 chars], 1)]
```

can anyone please help?

Comment: You should cast it to [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `response.data['results']` is an OrderedDict. An OrderedDict stores the order of the items when they were first added. The equivilent to this OrderedDict would be

```py
dict([('id', 7), ('title', 'bookmark'), ('color', 'yellow'), ('user', 2), ('project', 1)])
```

or

```py
[OrderedDict([('id', 7), ('title', 'bookmark'), ('color', 'yellow'), ('user', 2), ('project', 1)])
```

So the list you have right there isn't really the equivilent of the OrderedDict

Answer (score 0):

Those values aren't the same. The first is a list with a single item (an `OrderedDict`):

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 7), ('title', 'bookmark'), ('color', 'yellow'), ('user', 2), ('project', 1)])]
```

The second is a list of tuples:

```
[('id', 7), ('title', 'bookmark'), ('color', 'yellow'), ('user', 2), ('project', 1)]
```

`AssertEqual` is failing because they're not equal. You want:

```
self.assertEqual(
            response.data['results'],
            [OrderedDict([
                ('id', self.bookmark.id),
                ('title', self.bookmark.title),
                ('color', self.bookmark.color),
                ('user', self.bookmark.user.id),
                ('project', self.bookmark.project.id),
            ])]
        )
```